# Why is the order of my string getting mixed up after the mapping?

Tags: python, yield

I have some code below where we have a mapping of letters, with z=1, y=2,...,a=26. And we are given as an input a list of numberers in string format. And we need to return the corresponding word using the mapping.

```
def switcher(arr):
    int_arr= []
    final_arr = []
    for i in arr:
        int_arr.append(int(i))
    print(int_arr)

    ascii_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    ascii_letters.reverse()
    for i,l in enumerate(ascii_letters,1):
        for j in range(len(int_arr)):
            if int_arr[j] == i:
                final_arr.append(l)


    return final_arr

print(switcher(['24', '12', '23', '22', '4', '26', '9', '8']))
```

My question is for my code above- it works, but for some reason, the output letters are not printed in the right order. For example in the above the list of numbers should correspond to 'codewars', but I am getting 'wsroedca'. I can see it SPELLS codewords, but for some reason the order is getting mixed up, any ideas why this is? I know sets don't retain order but I haven't used a set in this case!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont have to overcomplicate it.
Just reverse letters and find the letter for a given index.

```
int_arr = [int(x)-1 for x in index]
word = []
letters.reverse()
for ind in int_arr:word.append(letters[ind])
print(''.join(word))
```

output

```
codewars
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But can you also kindly explain what is incorrect with my code? As I'd like to understand it. In particular why is the order being messed up? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Change to the below, you just have to call `ascii_letters[int_asci-1]` and this will return the corresponding letter.

```
def switcher(arr):
int_arr= []
final_arr = []
for i in arr:
    int_arr.append(int(i))
print(int_arr)

ascii_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
ascii_letters.reverse()
for int_asci in int_arr:
    final_arr.append(ascii_letters[int_asci-1])


return final_arr
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def switcher(arr):
    int_arr= []
    final_arr = []
    for i in arr:
        int_arr.append(int(i)-1)
    print(int_arr)

    ascii_letters = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    ascii_letters.reverse()
    return [ascii_letters[i] for i in int_arr]


    
print(switcher(['24', '12', '23', '22', '4', '26', '9', '8']))
```

Comment: Thanks for all the answers. But can someone explain what is wrong with my code? As I'd like to understand it. Thanks